# mouseenter not working on div img

Tags: jquery, html, css

making own slider using jquery
first list images from folder to div with class .list then using mouseenter to show each image in div id #show.
but mouseenter not working on ('.list img').
where is the problem?

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.1.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="show"></div>

    <div id="right">right</div>
    <div id="left">left</div>

    <div id="listwapper">
        <div class="list"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.list
{

    height:100px;
}
.list img
{
    width:98px;
    height:96px;
    border-right:1px solid #ffa800;
    border-left:1px solid #ffa800;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ffa800;
    border-top:2px solid #ffa800;
    border-radius:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#listwapper
{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#right
{
    float:right;
}
#left
{
    float:left;
}
#container
{
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:20px;
}
#show,#show img
{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

jquery:

```
$().ready(function(){
        var dir = "http://localhost/slider/images";
        var imageswidth = 0;
        $.ajax({
          url: dir,
          success: function(data){
             $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
                // will loop through 
                var images = $(this).attr("href");
                $('.list').append('<img class="image" src="'+ dir + '/' + images +'"></img>');
                imageswidth = imageswidth + 100;
                $(".list").css("width", imageswidth);
             }); 
          }
        });


        $('#right').mouseenter(function(){
            interval1 = setInterval(function(){
                $("#listwapper").animate({scrollLeft: '+=300'}, 500);
            },500);

        });

        $('.list img').mouseenter(function(){
            var imageUrl = $(this).attr("src");
            $('#show').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
        });


        $('#right').mouseleave(function(){
            clearInterval(interval1);
        });

        $('#left').mouseenter(function(){
            interval2 = setInterval(function(){
                $("#listwapper").animate({scrollLeft: '-=300'}, 500);
            },500);
        });

        $('#left').mouseleave(function(){
            clearInterval(interval2);
        });

});
```

Comment: You've executed the jQuery to bind an event to `.list img` before the ajax has finished, so before those images exist.

Comment: This question has been left in limbo, please mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the script runs on load, and doesn't wait for that ajax call to finish (unless you include the binding inside the success function), you've tried to bind the event to `.list img` before they exist.

`.list` exists, so instead of `$('.list img').mouseenter(function(){` delegate using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('.list').on('mouseenter', 'img', (function(){
```

This binds the event to `.list` but triggers on `.list img`

Answer (score 0):

`.list img` most likely doesn't exist in the DOM when you are binding your events due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Try using jquery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the event on the `list` but trigger the event on the `img`:

```
$('.list').on('mouseenter','img',function(){
    var imageUrl = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#show').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`mouseenter` will not work because you are binding the event before the DOM will be available in ajax.

Use [jQuery's .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','.list img',function(){
    var imageUrl = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#show').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
});
```